# Keep getting out of bound exception

Tags: c#, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following two methods implemented in C#

```
private static string FindLongestPalindrome(string s) 
{
    string largest = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= s.Length; j++)
        {
            if (IsPalindrome(s.Substring(i, j)))
            {
                largest = s.Substring(i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    return largest;
}

private static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
{
    bool isPalindrome = true;
    int j = s.Length-1;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i].ToString().ToLower() != s[j].ToString().ToLower())
        {
            isPalindrome = false;
            break;
        }

        j--;
    }

    return isPalindrome;
}
```

`IsPalindrome` checks if the string is a palindrome, and `FindLongestPalindrome` finds the longest palindrome in a string. Yes, I realize that `FindLongestPalindrome` is not the most efficient and is quadratic. I'm not concerned with that at the moment, however. I just simply want to know why at the following point the program keeps going out of bounds and throwing an exception:

```
if (IsPalindrome(s.Substring(i, j))) {...}
```

How can I modify this part so that the code doesn't go out of bounds for every string input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're attempting to retrieve too many characters out of your substring.

Your for loop:

```
for (int j = i+1; j <= s.Length; j++)
```

Should be:

```
for (int j = i; j <= s.Length - i; j++)
```

Notice the `s.Length - i`.

Your subsequent line:

```
if (IsPalindrome(s.Substring(i, j)))
```

Would fail with your first code because if `i` was `2`, you would eventually request: `s.Substring(2, s.Length)` which would try to retrieve more characters than are left in the string. <s>Really, you wanted (I think) to get the *rest* of the string, well, you can keep it as is, or just use the [`String.Substring(int)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which starts at that index and grabs the rest of the string.</s> EDIT: Nope, sorry, this a bad idea and fails for some tests.

Unfortunately, there are some other bugs in your code. For example, "banana" returns "ana" instead of "anana". Furthermore, if the longest palindrome started with the first letter of your input, it ignored it (because you start at `i = 1` instead of 0) A fixed version is here:

```
private static string FindLongestPalindrome(string s) 
{
    string largest = "";

    //start at i = 0 instead
    //Also needs to be to i < s.Length or fails some tests
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j <= s.Length-i; j++)
        {
            string substring = s.Substring(i, j);

            //you also need to check that you're looking at a longer string
            //this really could be optimized anyway, but here it is for simplicity
            if (substring.Length > largest.Length && IsPalindrome(substring))
            {
                largest = substring;
            }
        }
    }

    return largest;
}
```

With this, some tests:

```
banana --> anana
bananab --> bananab
zzz --> zzz
abcdddeeedddc --> cdddeeedddc
a --> a
abcbabbbbbbab --> babbbbbbab
```

Comment: Your second for loop code helped me fix my error. However, there is a problem with your new implementation of the method. It does not work for `abaccddccefe`

Comment: @Zolt: Sorry for that. I botched my thinking on how `s.Substring(i)` is being used in your algorithm. If you put it back to your original `s.Substring(i, j)` it works.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of this :

```
for (int j = i+1; j <= s.Length; j++)
```

it should be :

```
for (int j = i+1; j < s.Length; j++)
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not too sure. I just copy/pasted the code and still errored out. I think it's because of the `Subtring` call. It ends up trying to access too many characters. Say `i` is `2`, with your code update it will try to put in `Substring(2, s.Length -1)` which will error out. If you put `j < s.Length - i` it no longer errors but it's also not returning the _actual_ longest palindrome (it is returning a palindrome, just not the longest for me. For example, "banana" returns "nan" instead of "anana")

Comment: Simply removing the equal sign does not fix the problem. Still get the exception.

Comment: @Zolt can you give an example of your input ?

Comment: My input is `abaccddccefe`

Answer (score 1):

Is c# not c++....

```
   public static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
   {
      return s == new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());
   }
```

A suggest, add this as an extension method for the strings

```
public static class StringSupport
{
    public static bool IsPalindrome(this string s)
    {
        return s == new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}
```

For be used as this

```
bool palindrome = "string".IsPalindrome();
```

Comment: I really like your implementation of `IsPalindrome`. It works but I'm not sure why. I'm really interested to find out. Could you explain what this line is doing? `return s == new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());`

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your code more it makes perfect sense. You return the truth value of the comparison between the original string and a reversed string. I'm good now, thanks.

Comment: The code reverse the string in a char array, and after creates a new string for comparing it, it is easy to understand :)